# check if column exists VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I need to move data from Excel to Access using VBA. Currently I use `TransferSpreadhseet` method which works fine, but I need a way to add specific columns and also have the code fail if those columns do not exist. Also please note that I cannot use the Range as listed below because what if a column was deleted prior to the import? This is why I prefer to use column names.

My current code is:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 9, _ 
 "Employees","C:\exceldata\sheet1.xls", True, "A1:G12"
```

Comment: So if your source data (in excel) was correctly formatted, there would be no issue. Maybe formating the code prior to the import would help here.

Comment: I've been in this situation, many times.  I suggest importing that into a temporary table in your database.  You can then check if the [columns exist easier](http://forums.devarticles.com/microsoft-access-development-49/check-if-a-field-exists-in-a-table-using-vba-58559.html) and use Access to validate the data.  Next, you can do an [insert into a PermanentTable](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/949637-import-excel-cells-table-but-field-names-different-both)